# compilation linux kernel openssl/opensslv.h error

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to compile a Linux kernel without selecting the TCP/IP protocol in `menuconfig` but I face this error when I try to compile:

> scripts/sign-file.c:25:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such
>   file or directory

To compile I use this command:

```
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers
```

I'm working with linux-4.10.1's kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `make-kpkg` is a Debian-specific tool, I assume you are using a Debian distribution; you mentioned it is Ubuntu.

It looks like you don't have the dependencies for building the kernel installed.  You can install them (on Debian/Ubuntu) using:

```
# apt build-dep linux
```

If APT is missing source addresses, modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to contain a line as:

```
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ DIST main
```

It should be commented in that file (so prefixed with a #). If so, just remove the #, otherwise copy the `deb ...` line and change `deb` to `deb-src`. Remember to reload package sources afterwards:

```
# apt update
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer I'm using Ubuntu but I read the command was the same

Comment: You're welcome. If it works, feel free to accept/upvote my answer :-).

Comment: actually I've got this answer "E: You need to insert some "source" addresses into your sources.list"

Comment: I've extended my answer