# Compiling Linux Kernel 5.2.9 fails at scripts/sign-file

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

I am trying to compile my own kernel for the sake of experience. The kernel version is 5.2.9 downloaded from kernel.org today ( Aug 19, 2019 ).
my make command is "make -j 6". I have a Ryzen 7 1700x 8 core / 16 thread amd cpu.

scripts/sign-file.c:25:10:fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
   25 | #include 
      |
compilation terminated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compilation linux kernel openssl/opensslv.h error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652963/compilation-linux-kernel-openssl-opensslv-h-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to my reputation, This is like the link belowed answers:

[How to fix: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory in RedHat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008624/how-to-fix-fatal-error-openssl-opensslv-h-no-such-file-or-directory-in-redhat)

In short, you need install ssl development packet.
On Debian-like dist, you need:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

On centos-like, install it:

```sh
sudo yum install openssl-devel
```